# Кастомизация Spring JPA: PropertyReferenceException: No property customize found for type ImageFile!

Tags: java, spring, spring-jpa

Кастомизирую `Spring Jparepository`.

**Вот интерфейс:**

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ImageRepositoryCustom<T extends ImageAbstract,
           P extends EntityPathBase<T>, ID extends Serializable>
           extends JpaRepository<T, ID>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<T>,
           QuerydslBinderCustomizer<P> {
}
```

От него наследуется интерфейс, с которым я уже планирую работать:

```
@Repository
public interface ImageFileRepository extends ImageRepositoryCustom<ImageFile, 
           QImageFile, Long> {
}
```

**Конец стектрейса:**

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
>   property customize found for type ImageCategory!

Ошибка распространённая, но из ответов я ничего не понял (точнее, пробовал исправить, но ничего не получилось, а хочется именно понять, что не так и по каким правилам это работает).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача решилась следующим образом (во всяком случае, Spring стал подниматься):

Добавил `(Implement methods)` в `ImageRepositoryCustom` метод `customize();` и всё заработало.

Ведь в стектрейсе запрашивало именно его.

Comment: Если добавить через Override Methods, то не работает.